# Trouble with "Git"

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I recently started git and it has been giving me some problems for example, when I try to create a new branch or anything it simple tells me that the name can not be used. I've looked at the reference but it hasn't helped me in the slightest. It also seems that a few codes don't work on the reference. I don't ask that you do everything but I ask that you help me in whatever way, so will you help me?

A side not for you, all results that I get to try and get help for git are for the Mac version and not the PC, so it's very annoying since the features are almost different entirely.

**EDIT:** Here's an example, "git branch 'Trace_Flora'" I will get the following text of "fatal: Not a valid object name: 'Example'" and the same thing happens if I use "/"

Comment: What commands are you running?  Is this a GUI or command line client?

Comment: I'll use an example, "Git branch 'Trace/Flora'" (not something I used, it was simply a example)

Comment: It would be more helpful to post an example that *doesn't* work, along with the error message.

Comment: @chepner It has been created, you may understand what my trouble is.

Comment: @chepner It has been created, you may understand my problem (sorry if it sounds the same, I edited the last comment)

Comment: Which is it, Trace_Flora or Example?

Comment: @chepner the problem is with "Trace_Flora" it is an example because I don't want to exactly give away information, it's a small work project and all that, so you could understand my secrecy. I also can't give you picture information because this is a work computer and screenshots have been disabled (or the buttons have been changed, don't know). Ignore that last part if you want

Comment: Well thank you all for the very amazing help. Even if not for me but for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the features should be identical regardless of your client.  Most examples will be Linux, not Mac.  If you prefer to use a graphical client, I've found that [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) works well.

To create a new branch, use `git checkout -b <branchname>`.  Don't use spaces in your branch name.

Comment: Thank you, you've been a create help. It seems that sometimes it's better to ask for help than it is trying to do it yourself. I've had a bad reputation with asking for help on the internet with it leading me almost no where at all

Comment: No problem.  Don't forget to upvote helpful answers.  Also, the '/' should work but you will have to enclose the branch name in quotes as in `git checkout -b 'Trace/Flora'`

Comment: the "/" seems to not work for me even when I use quotes, no idea why

Answer (score 0):

You may want to avoid special chars like '/' in the branch name.  Try it with the basic alpha numeric chars like `a-z 0-9 _`  Like

```
git branch Trace_Flora
```

This will create a branch *from* the current branch you're on.

Comment: Thank you for your input, it hasn't helped me exactly however I will keep it in mind. I'm sorry if I come off rude

Comment: That is ok.  If you want to checkout the branch in your workspace, that is a separate command, eg `git checkout Trace_Flora`.  If that doesn't work, I might try reinstalling or updating your git client... might be corrupted if that doesn't work.

Comment: `/` is perfectly legal in a branch name.

Comment: Okay, and thank you again, I'll keep you in mind and hey! If I could up your comment I would

Comment: @chepner in this case it isn't, while it's considered legal it could be for certain software or other places of code.

Comment: We haven't established that `/` is the problem, because you haven't provided us with the exact problem you are having. Do you get an error message like `fatal: 'Trace/flora' is not a valid branch name.`?